# winros: can't find tf/tfMessage type?

Tags: ros, winros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully built the WinROS sdk and samples using VS2010.
I have created a simple program that writes messages to a bag file.

My ultimate goal is to write tf/tfMessage type messages to the /tf topic in a bag, then to play that bag on Ubuntu for other existing nodes listening on that topic, but I don't see the tf/tfMessage type defined anywhere (thought it would be in "geometry_msgs").

I can write geometry_msgs/TransformStamped type messages which seem to have the same data, but are not compatible with the /tf topic.

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120986/winros:-can%27t-find-tf/tfmessage-type?/) by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on 2014-01-23**:
Can someone confirm that tf is not ported to winros?  I just want to know that I'm not missing something.  Seems like a very important library so I thought it was, but maybe not.

**Comment by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on 2014-01-23**:
Also, upon further inspection it appears that the tf/tfMessage is just an array of geometry_msgs/TransfromStamped type messages.
Can someone confirm that for me?   I'm thinking it might not be that hard to mock-up one of these in that namespace and copy the MD5 from the real one and make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indeed, tf has not yet been ported to windows. We were backing off from doing that because of the move from tf to tf2 and we also didn't have a use case for it ourselves.

Be great if someone stepped in and did it. Certainly would be useful for alot of folk.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gershon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4399/gershon/) on 2014-01-29**:
I understand.  Thanks.

**Comment by [tav](https://answers.ros.org/users/20091/tav/) on 2014-08-26**:
Hi there, I am now looking for tf/transform_broadcaster.h win winros and I cannot find it too in the new version (sdk-hydro-x86-vs10-0.3.1). Has it still not ported into the winros after almost 7 months?